# Orientation of an image from its metadata(using Exif) for the image loaded using background-image style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, exif-js

I need to get the orientation of an image from its metadata(using Exif) after it gets loaded in the page.

I have two scenarios to cover:

First: Image is loaded in `<img>` tag

```
<div><img id="uploadImg1" class="img-fluid" src="source-image-path" alt=""></div>
```

I can get the image meta data details using below lines of code:

var newimg = document.getElementById("#ImageId");

EXIF.getTag(newimg, "Orientation"); // Exif.js is the external file downloaded to get exif details of an image. And using this we can get the image details.

It is working fine.

---

Second: When I am using background-image to load an image inside the div directly.

```
<div class="demo-drop" id="uploadImg2" style="background-image: url(source-image-path);"><div>
```

I am not able to get the image details here. Any idea how can i get the image meta data details in this case ?

Comment: there is no way, because there is no image in your second snippet. Background images are only CSS styles, there is no img element in the DOM. You could load your image in javascript, then pass it as a background to the `demo-drop` element